# How to translte some phrases M2

Tags: magento2, translate

I want to translate this [image: message]

I added in my `fr_FR.csv` those lines but with no results:

> "You added %1 to your shopping cart.","Vous avez ajouté %1 à votre panier."
>   "You added %1 to your", "You added %1 to your"
>   "shopping cart.", "panier."

The shopping cart is cliquable to the cart

Comment: I think you have added a link to your "shopping cart" text. Thats why its not working.

Comment: you can add here text above

Comment: no i addede nothing it's the template that shows the text like this

Comment: which theme you are using ?

Comment: Smartwave/porto

Comment: any live link available or above text?

Comment: You added Piqûres brouillon stapled draft books 16,5x21cm-5x5+mr-100 to your shopping cart.

Comment: yes https://www.portotheme.com/magento2/porto/demo19_en